# Setting the xterm window title on Ubuntu sets the wrong title

Tags: ubuntu, cygwin, xorg, xterm, cygwin-x

I'm trying to set the window and icon title for `xterm` on Ubuntu 17.

```
odin:~% grep PRET /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 17.04"
odin:~% printf "\e]0;%s\a" X00X
odin:~% xterm -help
XTerm(324) usage:
```

The window title ends up getting set to "X00X@odin" (the hostname).

I can't seem to find where my text string is getting changed.  Does
anyone know how to shut this off?

It works correctly on Cygwin xterm (XTerm(330)).

Thanks.

-E

I ran this in a `csh` to avoid any `bash` `PROMPT_COMMAND` situations.